# jquery val() coming up as blank after .each()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm iterating with

```
function editRow(a) {
  $("td").each(function () {
    alert($(this).val())
  });
}
```

which iterates through

```
$("tbody").append(
  "<tr id = '" + trId + "'>" +
  "<td name = 'nameRow' id = 'name" + idCt + "'  value = 'test' > <strong>" + name + "</strong> </td>" +
  "<td name = 'maxRow' id = 'max" + idCt + "'  value = '" + max + "'>" + max + "</td>" +
  "<td name = 'setRow' id = 'sets" + idCt + "' value = '" + sets + "'>" + sets + "</td>" +
  "<td name = 'repRow' id = 'reps" + idCt + "' value = '" + reps + "'>" + reps + "</td>" +
  "<td name = 'restRow' id = 'rest" + idCt + "' value = '" + rest + "'>" + rest + "</td>" +
  "<td id = 'link" + idCt + "'><a href='#' onclick='return deleteRow(" + trId + ");' >Remove</a>" +
  " | <a href='#' onclick='return editRow(" + idCt + ");'>Edit</a></td>" +
  "</tr>"
);
```

The `alter($(this).val())` is coming up the correct amount of times, but it is always just blank (not undefined)).

I know it's not that readable, but does anyone see an error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.val()` is a method which is only defined for input elements. Normal HTML elements don't have a value. You should use `.html()` or `.text()` to get the content of those elements

```
function editRow(a) {
    $("td").each(function () {
        alert($(this).text())
    });
}
```

You should define non-standard attributes (like value for `<td>`) using the `data-` prefix

```
<td data-value="whatever">...</td>
```

Then you can use jQuery's `.data()` method to access those attributes

```
var tdDataValue = $(this).data('value');
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that "td" - elements haven't values. They have inner HMTL. If you want to get td's content, you need to use $(this).html()

```
function editRow(a) {
$("td").each(function () {
    alert($(this).html())
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The `val` method is usually reserved for `input` tags. For `td` you can do either:

`$(this).text();`

or

`$(this).attr('value');`

Answer (score 0):

simply try something like this

```
function editRow(a) {
    $("td").each(function () {
        alert(this.innerText);// reading inner text
        alert($(this).attr('value'));// reading value attribute
    });
}
```